# Regex - Validation of numeric with up to 4 decimal places

Tags: regex

I am having a bit of difficulty with the following:

I need to allow any positive numeric value up to four decimal places. Here are some examples.

**Allowed:**

```
123
12345.4
1212.56
8778787.567
123.5678
```

**Not allowed:**

```
-1
12.12345
-12.1234
```

I have tried the following:

```
^[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$|^(100)(\.[0]{1,4})?$
```

However this doesn't seem to work, e.g. 1000 is not allowed when it should be.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what language, tool, or library does the regex need to be compatible with?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To explain why your attempt is not working for a value of `1000`, I'll break down the expression a little:

```
^[0-9]{0,2}             # Match 0, 1, or 2 digits (can start with a zero)...
(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$        # ... optionally followed by (a decimal, then 1-4 digits)
|                       # -OR-
^(100)                  # Capture 100...
(\.[0]{1,4})?$          # ... optionally followed by (a decimal, then 1-4 ZEROS)
```

There is no room for 4 digits of any sort, much less `1000` (theres only room for a 0-2 digit number or the number 100)

```
^\d*                    # Match any number of digits (can start with a zero)
(\.\d{1,4})?$           # ...optionally followed by (a decimal and 1-4 digits)
```

This expression will pass any of the **allowed** examples and reject all of the **Not Allowed** examples as well, because you (and I) use the beginning-of-string assertion `^`.

It will also pass these numbers:

```
.2378
1234567890
12374610237856987612364017826350947816290385
000000000000000000000.0
0
```

... as well as a completely blank line - which might or might not be desired

to make it reject something that starts with a zero, use this:

```
^(?!0\d)\d*             # Match any number of digits (cannot "START" with a zero)
(\.\d{1,4})?$           # ...optionally followed by (a decimal and 1-4 digits)
```

This expression (which uses a negative lookahead) has these evaluations:

```
REJECTED                Allowed
---------               -------
0000.1234               0.1234
0000                    0
010                     0.0
```

You could also test for a completely blank line in other ways, but if you wanted to reject it with the regex, use this:

```
^(?!0\d|$)\d*(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for the clear breakdown. This was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]{0,4})?$
```

Explanation: match only if starting with a digit (excluding negative numbers), optionally followed by (non-capturing group) a dot and 0-4 digits.

**Edit:** With this pattern `.2134` would also be matched. To only allow  0 < x < 1 of format `0.2134`, replace the first `*` with a `+` above.

Answer (score 1):

This regex would do the trick:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

From the beginning of the string search for one or more digits. If there's a `.` it must be followed with atleast one digit  but a maximum of 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?<!-)\+?\d+(\.?\d{0,4})?$
```

The will match something with doesn't start with -, maybe has a + followed by an integer part with at least one number and an optional floating part of maximum 4 numbers.

Note: Regex does **not** support scientific notation. If you want that too let me know in a comment.

Comment: The `(?<!-)` is not needed.  By writing `^\+`, a leading negative sign is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Well asked!!
You can try this:

```
^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a double value but it goes to more decimal format and you want to shorter it to 4 then !

```
   double value = 12.3457652133
  value =Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.####").format(value));
```